# React native - CFBundleIdentifier does Not Exist

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, visual-studio

I am trying to run a React native project to iPad from Visual Studio code but I am getting the following error

```
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-video: https://npmjs.com/package/react-native-video
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
info Found Xcode workspace "LibApp.xcworkspace"
info Launching iPad Air (4th generation) (iOS 14.4)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace LibAppe.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme LibApp -destination id=EB7F93D3-C4CE-4DED-9E30-D0F155BFF116")    .......................................................................................................................................
info Installing "/Users/Siva/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LibApp-aulzxshtfadmpwgvkbujhecsczsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React/LibApp.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
error Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier /Users/Siva/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LibApp-aulzxshtfadmpwgvkbujhecsczsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React/LibApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier /Users/Siva/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LibApp-aulzxshtfadmpwgvkbujhecsczsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React/LibApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:826:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:864:15)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/Siva/Desktop/LibApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:183:45)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/Siva/Desktop/LibApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:182:9)
```

But when I run the same code from Xcode, the app gets launched in Simulator
and I am able to check it.

How to fix this error

Comment: had you fixed this issue??

Comment: I have the same issue. I figured that the path includes an additional "React/".

````
Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React/LibApp.app
````

I am not sure how to fix it.